# bash or vimscript, how terminate script but leaving apps it started still running

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, vim

In either bash or vimscript, how can I run a script that starts an app (xv or display) and have the script terminate by returning focus to vim, but
 leaving xv/display still running. My current effort is this vim function, which is essentially a vim directed version of my attempt in bash. It hangs at the last command until I quit display.

```
" S() is called internally by :F to show images appropriately
function! S(j,k)
if system("pgrep ".a:j)!=''
exe '!pkill '.a:j
endif
exe '!'.a:j.' -geometry +0+'.a:k.@u.' &'
wmctrl -a Botany
endfunction
```

a:j is appname, a:k is screen position parameter, @u is filepath

Comment: You mean how to run something in the background, with `&`?

Answer (score 1):

A typical bash script would look like

```
#!/bin/bash

# Configuration
CMD="xv -some -parameters /and/a/path"
STDOUTLOG="/path/to/logfile"
STDERRLOG="/dev/null"

/bin/bash -c "eval '$CMD'" >"$STDOUTLOG" 2>"$STDERRLOG" &
```

Comment: I'd never used environment variables before, and didn't understand what you were trying to tell me here; then came across the subject in another context, and it finally clicked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you cannot dissociate an app from the process that launched it, the solution, that works for me, is to have some other process, already running, do that for me.  Here is my solution:

```
pkill -n xterm
cd /mnt/0/botany
xterm -g 80x59+885+0 -title 'Botany' -e vim -S bot.vim -o g y d "+res 8|2winc w|res 30" &
xp=
dp=
while ps ax|grep Botany|grep -v grep; do
  if [ -f q ]; then
    s=$(cat q)
    rm q
    if [[ "$s" =~ 'images.*' ]]; then
      kill $dp 2> /dev/null
      vd="$s $vd"
      xv -geometry +0+380 ${vd% *} &
      dp=$(pgrep xv|tail -1)
    else
      kill $xp 2> /dev/null
      vx="$s $vx"
      xv -geometry +0+0 ${vx% *} &
      xp=$(pgrep xv|tail -1)
    fi
    sleep 1
    wmctrl -a Botany
  fi
done
kill $dp $xp 2> /dev/null
```

The first three commands, to the xterm, comprise the original script I used to open this project, so this script continued open and waiting until the time I closed out vim and let the xterm die, at which point this calling script would close out too.  So here was a handy running process, doing nothing, and in the very directory I was working in.
  I added the rest of the code, which checks for the existence of a file q, reads it and immediately destroys it and kills any running instance of the viewer. then restarts the viewer using the filepath from file q as the image to show.
All completely dissociated from vim, where my vimscript just writes the filepath to file q, and never references the viewer app, xp.